# How to share methods in derived classes without including in base class

Tags: java, inheritance, design-patterns

I have a class `BinarySearchTree` which is extended by `AVLTree` and `RedBlackTree`. The two derived classes support rotation hence need to use `rotateLeft` and `rotateRight` method. One way is to implement these two methods in `BinarySearchTree` so that they are available to `AVLTree` and `RedBlackTree`, but these methods do not belong to `BinarySearchTree` as it does not support rotation as such. How should I handle this situation in Java?

Comment: If I use an abstract class how will it solve my purpose? My classes already extend one class BinarySearchTree.

Comment: Great Point!! You can only inherit from one class - that's true. My bad.

Comment: I edited my answer. Yes, what you are looking for is an interface.

Comment: Let me think about this for a sec, there may be a better solution. @akhil_mittal

Comment: okay my conclusion is: you have to implement them separately. I just edited my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an intermediate class `abstract class RotatableBinarySearchTree extends BinarySearchTree`, have it define protected methods `rotateLeft` and `rotateRight`, and then have `AVLTree` and `RedBlackTree` extend from RotatableBinarySearchTree rather than BinarySearchTree.

This meets your goal of sharing the concrete implementation between classes, without having to add the code to BinarySearchTree, which by itself is not rotatable.  If you use a `Rotatable` interface, then you will have to either duplicate the logic in both subclasses, or use some sort of injection, which to me seems unnecessarily complex for this scenario.

If you're unfamiliar with abstract classes, see the link that Steve shared in the comments.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion :)

Using an abstract class with no abstract method does not seem a nice option to me.

Comment: @akhil_mittal It's a valid use case.  See the [Abstract Methods and Classes tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html) - _"You want to share code among several closely related classes"_ is listed as one of the reasons to consider using an abstract class

Comment: The first line in the tutorial says it all, "An *abstract class* is a class that is declared `abstract`—it may or may not include abstract methods. Abstract classes cannot be instantiated, but they can be subclassed."

Answer (score 1):

define an interface called e.g. "Rotatable", and make your subclasses to implement that besides extending from the base class

Comment: In that case I would have to implement those methods in both the classes. But methods body would be same in both. Isn't this repetition of code?

Comment: In case the method implementations should be the same, then yes it is. For me this did not come through the question, my understanding was that these are different tree data structures, in which the nodes are organized in some different way, and rotating those nodes would also mean different algorithms to be implemented. If it is not the situation, then to avoid duplicate code, Kevin K's answer seems to be the ticket to you.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new Interface say RotatingTree which has those two methods, implement it in a class and inject it at runtime into your AvlTree or RedBlackTree.

```
class BinarySearchTree<T> {
    public void add(T element) {}
}
class RedBlackTree extends BinarySearchTree {
   private RotatingTree rotationPolicy;
   public AVLTree (RotatingTree rotationPolicy) {
       this.rotationPolicy = rotationPolicy;
   }
   public void add(T element) {
       rotationPolicy.rotateLeft();//...and so on
   }
}
class AVLTree extends BinarySearchTree {
   private RotatingTree rotationPolicy;
   public AVLTree (RotatingTree rotationPolicy) {
       this.rotationPolicy = rotationPolicy;
   }
   public void add(T element) {
       rotationPolicy.rotateRight();//...and so on
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define an `interface` that includes those two methods, and implement them in the sub-classes. Here are the caveats:

```
 A Java interface is just like an abstract class, except for two differences.
(1)  In Java, a class can inherit from only one class, even if the superclass
 is an abstract class.  However, a class can "implement" (inherit from) as
 many Java interfaces as you like.

(2)  A Java interface cannot implement any methods, nor can it include any
 fields except "final static" constants.  It only contains method
 prototypes and constants.
```

Because a class can only inherit from one class, unless you want to define rotateLeft and rotateRight in the class BinarySearchTree, you have to implement the methods in the sub-classes separately and repetitively. (Only their prototypes are defined in the interface)

Comment: He could use default method implementations on a common interface, which would not require specific implementations on each subclass

Comment: @Alex IMHO The sole purpose of introduction of default methods is to provide extensibility to existing interfaces. I will keep that option at last.